# Ms graph api send invitation works , but external user is not added

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I would add external user to my tenant in order to use their identity in my app.

I send invitation using `/invitations` endpoint

the invitation created and sent

[image]

User receives mail invitation and accept it => redirection to `redurectUrl` ok

Then when I try to search for user in Teams search bar or using [mgt-people-picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/toolkit/components/people-picker)

No result is found.

I checked the guest users in 365 Admin center : list is empty.

What should I do to get user in my tenant ?

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully as below:***

I **Invited the user** using the below Graph API query:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations
Content-type: application/json

{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "xxx@xxx.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://testruk3394.contoso.com"
}
```

[image]

Now, the user got the invitation via mail, here the user must accept the invitation:

[image]

Once the user accepts the invitation, **the user is added in the Azure Portal as a guest user** like below:

[image]

When I checked in [Guest users - Microsoft 365 admin center](https://admin.microsoft.com/Adminportal/Home#/GuestUsers), the user is present like below:

[image]

- Verify whether you have required privileges (Admin) to view the Guest users.
- Check whether you are trying to add correct email address while searching in teams as users might have multiple email address.

Check whether the **Guest User State is Accepted** in the Azure Portal as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works actually yes using another email than gmail( may be the issue is from a specific email adresse ) ,  I can found the user in Teams , the issue now is when I use PeoplePicker component: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/mgt-react
I don't find it

Comment: I don't find the user

Comment: Could you paste the snip of the error you are getting?